# Recording Videos in Chunks Using Media Recorder Android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I am implementing an Application that includes the functionality of saving Recorded Video in to Different Video Files based on a certain amount of Time.

For Achieving that i have implemented a Custom Camera and used the `MediaRecorder.stop()` and `MediaRecorder.start()` in a certain Loop.

But this approach is creating a Lag Effect while restarting Media Recorder (Stop and Start). Is it possible to seamlessly Stop and Start Recording using Media Recorder or any Third Party Library ?

Any help is Highly Appreciated.

Comment: I am using a custom camera and Media Recorder for recording Video.

Comment: I see, you want to split a video into sections as and when it is being recorded. However I think, if you record the complete video, and then later perform the splitting action on the complete chunk, would be the easiest way forward. Or if your requirements want you to persist with splitting the video at the time of recording itself, you should maintain a buffer. DO not feed the stream directly from Camera to Video Recorder . Just introduce a buffer between these two components.

Comment: Your approach seems interesting, Please elaborate how do i maintain a Buffer ?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani I know it's been a long time, but i'm interested in knowing how did you manage to solve this out. Did you end up using MediaCodec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the best solution to implement chunks recording is to set maximum time in MediaRecorder Object

```
mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(CHUNK_TIME);
```

then you can attach an info listener, it will intimate you when it will hit maximum chunk time

```
mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
  @Override
  public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
        // restartVideo()
    }
 }
});
```

in restartVideo you should firstly clear previous MediaRecorder Object and start video again.

Comment: From this response it looks like you might be able to help answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659380/how-to-get-android-video-capture-to-survive-screen-rotation it is about filming to an existing file.

Comment: this will give you small gaps from video to video

Comment: @fabricio that is true, Android by default takes around 1-2 second when it restarts video recorder.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two instances of MediaRecorder which will overlap slightly (i.e. when the stream is  close to the end of the first chunk you can prepare and start the second one). It is possible to record 2 video files using 2 MediaRecorders at the same time if they capture only the video. Unfortunately sharing the mic between 2 MediaRecorder instances is not supported.