# How to get android video capture to survive screen rotation

Tags: android, video, android-orientation, android-mediarecorder, android-configchanges

I have managed to get [Video capture to work for a custom camera experience](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) (i.e. using MediaRecorder, Camera, SurfaceView, etc.). But if I am recording a video and change the orientation of the device, video capture stops. Is there  way to continue the capture after the orientation change? If fact I want the capture to continue no matter how many times the orientation changes. I imagine it might all have to do with `savedInstanceState` and saving the file that I pass to `mRecorder.setOutputFile(my file)`. If that's correct, what else am I missing? Or is there a more standard way to handle orientation change during video recording? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: In other words, I need to know how to **append** to an existing video file.

Comment: btw the following is not enough: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` with or without `setContentView`. The default camera on my device handles it seamlessly. I hope someone here can help.

Comment: Perhaps `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, then detect and handle the orientation change?